# Using zcat and gzip in linux

Tags: linux

I used `zcat` and `gzip` to merge and zip the files using:

```
zcat file1.fastq.gz file2.fastq.gz | gzip -c > file1.fastq.gz
```

Now, I have 0 bytes `file1.fastq.gz`

Please advise?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `>` redirection, the shell will open the named file (`file1.fastq.gz`) for writing and truncate it to zero length. ([documentation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html))

Next, `zcat` will run, with `file1.fastq.gz` and `file2.fastq.gz` as input files .

At this point, `zcat` throws an error, because the input file (`file1.fastq.gz`) has no content - not even the GZip header - and the pipeline falls apart.

You may find that `file1.fastq.gz` is actually a few bytes in size (not zero), and this will be caused by `gzip` compressing and writing its null input.

```
$ echo "foo" | gzip > file1.gz
$ echo "bar" | gzip > file2.gz
$ zcat file1.gz file2.gz | gzip -c > file1.gz

gzip: file1.gz: unexpected end of file
$ stat -c '%s bytes' file1.gz
20 bytes
```

It's worth looking out for error messages like this.

---

There are a couple of viable solutions, but they depend on the size of your data.

In all situations, without some clever tricks, you will need to have enough space to store both the original *and* the new output file on disk at once.

#### Write to Another File

```
$ echo "foo" | gzip > file1.gz
$ echo "bar" | gzip > file2.gz
$ zcat file1.gz file2.gz | gzip -c > file_all.gz
$ gzip -d < file_all.gz
foo
bar
```

#### Use `sponge`

If the data isn't too large, then the `sponge` utility will handle this situation for you. All data read from stdin is "*soaked up*" before any data is written to the output file.

```
$ echo "foo" | gzip > file1.gz
$ echo "bar" | gzip > file2.gz
$ zcat file1.gz file2.gz | gzip -c | sponge file1.gz
$ gzip -d < file1.gz
foo
bar
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, it is not empty. I tried these commands but it didn't work

Comment: Is it possible to recover the old file? Thanks

Comment: The file 1 is 20 bytes while file 2 is 2.3GB, the file 1 was earlier 2.3 GB, i want to get both file 1 and file 2 as 2.3 GB

Comment: "_Is it possible to recover the old file?_" probably not... can you get / create it again?

Comment: "*is it possible to recover the old file?*" https://superuser.com/questions/1124811/what-should-do-now-that-i-have-accidentally-truncated-a-file-i-dont-have-a-back/1124824#1124824 https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device